# The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable on .exe files created from VS

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

So, all the `.exe` files that I am creating from Microsoft Visual Studio keep on throwing an error message `The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable` when I want to run them. This is only happening in a specific Windows 10 machine. The same is not happening on other Windows 10 machines. I have tried to recreate the `.exe` both from VS 2017 and VS2019. I have also tried to create WPF, Win Forms and Console Apps. The issue remains, as long it is a `.exe` created from VS. Other `.exe` files, for example, `.exe` downloaded from the internet or the ones in the Program Files are running perfectly fine. I read about running the `scs \scannow` and still, the issue persists.

[image: Here is the error message.]

Anyone who may be faced this before and how you solved it?

Comment: What happens if you take the `.exe` on the "bad" machine and move it to a "good" machine?

Comment: Does the error occur if you copy the bad .exe to a new machine?  Does a "good" exe copied to the bad machine work correctly?

Comment: @MikeH, @kit So, I then copied back the corrupted `.exe` file from the "bad" machine to the "good" machine and the error happened as well on the "good" machine. Which implies something might be corrupting the `.exe` files on the "bad" machine.

Comment: If the exe is consitetnly broken, it sounds like the Compiler or IDE are most likely at fault.

Comment: @Christopher I agree.  I would say the IDE, but the OP indicated the problem is with both VS2017 and VS2019.  I wonder if there is a compiler flag or option that could affect both.

Comment: @Christopher I would not say the `.exe` is consistently broken. It works perfectly fine on other machines. It is only when the file is copied to a specific machine where the file is becoming permanently corrupted that you can not even run it on the other machines where it was running perfectly fine before.

Comment: "So, I then copied back the corrupted .exe file from the "bad" machine to the "good" machine and the error happened as well on the "good" machine" It see clear that files **build on this computer** are consistently broken.

Comment: @MikeH IIRC the .NET framework actually brought a compiler along. If VS is using that one, it would be broken for all installations. | Alternatively, Programms can share files. That is what the special folder `CommonProgramFiles` is there for. VS might just do that to save disk space.

Answer (score 0):

> So, all the .exe files that I am creating from Microsoft Visual Studio keep on throwing an error message The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable when I want to run them. This is only happening in a specific Windows 10 machine.

As the problem only happens with one machine, it seems clear that *something* is broken on that machine. Either with the OS (unlikely), the IDE or Compiler Installation, or at least that speicific folder.

Edit: As the behavior follows the file around, we can asume it is not the OS. Only something with the build process.

You could try by removing that folder, then making a clean reinstall of the IDE and Framework. But the reliable solution would be to just reinstall that computer from the Filesystem upwards. This is the kind of bug you can spend days trying to debug and still not get anywhere. And even if you could fix it, could you realy rely on the computer to not have other criticial bugs? Maybe ones that do not show a helpfull error message?

As you already verified it happens on no other machines and it persits for any .exe created on this machine, it would at best be trivia to figure out what *precisely* is wrong. I can give you a rough idea:

Some file got binary damage while in ram or on disk. Either that file was the compiler, or a file that then went on the corrupt the compiler, or a file that corrupted the file that would end up corrupting the compiler. As we are not dealing with the kind of hardware that has to run a mars rover, guided missile system or nuclear power plant, those things happen.

Answer (score 0):

This error is often a sign of disk/file system defects.

1. I'd try to **move the compiled files** out of this folder into
   another folder, preferably on another (physical) drive. Then check
   if it runs there.
2. If option 1 does not work you could then try to **re-build the files** into another folder, also on another (physical) drive preferably.

If one of both of the above solutions works, thats an indication you indeed might have FS/HDD trouble. Try running `chkdsk /f c:` on the offending drive to check for errors.

If this also does not work, try re-installing Visual Studio.

Comment: The OP has already indicated that the problem follows the .exe, even to another computer.

Comment: Good ideas with those repair steps. But I really think it is better to just reinstall it. Maybe check the RAM with a tool like Memtest. If it has that kind of error, it propably has other kinds of errors.

Comment: @MikeH: True, I just illustrated my line of thought. Hence the second step I suggested. This step could lead to the conclusion that the build itself is cause of trouble and therefore a re-install of VS could be beneficial...

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I was experiencing the stated issue is because of the data transfer methods (Teamviewer, AnyDesk and Microsoft Remote Desktop) I was using to move files between the two computers.

I discovered that the issue was not only about `.exe` files. Any file I copied across to this specific Windows 10 machine that was giving an issue, I could not open it. It could throw the same error message. In this case, I accept that this an OS issue. However, I was not prepared to reinstall the machine.

So, to resolve the issue, I did use FTP to move the files between the two computers. I uploaded the `.exe` file to FTP Server from the one computer and downloaded the `.exe` on the other computer that was giving issues. Downloaded files could then open without any issues.